# Too many (recovered) exceptions in Azure App Insights

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-application-insights, azure-ad-msal, openiddict

I have a problem: Application Insights is getting too many **false positive** and is sending mails on exceptions that, after investigation, cause no problem to our application

### Summary, TL;DR

This is a X->Y problem. Problem Y is that AAI is logging a large number of server exceptions, see detailed explanation, and sending alerts to us. Problem X is that the JWT authentication middleware is throwing exceptions about unmatched key, but is recovering all of them swithching to a different OIDC provider. With the result that the invocation succeeds.

What can I do in order to either fix or whitelist these exceptions?

Question 2: when do exceptions get logged to AAI? Only when they are unhandled or when the logger decides to?

### Context

Our application receives email data from Twilio Sendgrid via authenticated webhooks. It also allows our B2C tenant users to access the application and browse data/statistics.

B2C does not allow client credentials flow, **and** Sendgrid does not support scopes. **In the end** we ended up using two OIDC providers: Azure AD B2C for interactive users, and [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict) in memory to authenticate the Sendgrid service to us.

### Some code

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

        services.AddLogging(
            configuration => configuration
                .AddApplicationInsights()
                .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace)
                .AddConsole()
        );

        services.ConfigureOpenIddictAuthentication();

        services
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration)
            //.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            //.AddInMemoryTokenCaches()
            ;

        services.AddAuthorization(authorization => authorization
            .AddPolicy("AzureSendgridPolicy", policy => policy
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            )
        );
    }

    public static IServiceCollection ConfigureOpenIddictAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<OpenIddictDbContext>(ef => ef
                // Configure the context to use an in-memory store.
                // This prevents multiple cluster instances from deployment
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(nameof(OpenIddictDbContext))
                // Register the entity sets needed by OpenIddict.
                .UseOpenIddict()
            )
            .AddOpenIddict(options =>
                options.AddServer(server => server
                        .DisableAccessTokenEncryption() //Just for development

                        //Development: no time to waste on certificate management today
                        .AddEphemeralEncryptionKey()
                        .AddEphemeralSigningKey()
                        .RegisterClaims(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Role)
                        .RegisterScopes(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles)
                        .SetTokenEndpointUris("/api/v1/Auth/token")
                        .SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/api/v1/Auth/authorize")
                        .AllowClientCredentialsFlow() //Only one supported by Sendgrid
                        .UseAspNetCore()
                        .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough())
                    .AddCore(core => core.UseEntityFrameworkCore(ef => ef.UseDbContext<OpenIddictDbContext>()))
                    .AddValidation(validation => validation
                        .UseLocalServer(_ => {})
                        .UseAspNetCore(_ => {})
                    )
            )
            .AddHostedService<OpenIddictHostedService>()
            .AddAuthentication()
            ;

        return services;
    }
```

### Azure Application Insights

On AAI, I find that the most frequent exception thrown is `SecurityTokenUnableToValidateException`

[image: AAI dashboard]

It is thrown a large number of times, fairly more than the real `401`s. Because of the ephemeral key in dev environment, every time the application is restarted the JWK is regenerated by OpenIddict.

But looking better at some traces, I discover that it is not an error

[image: AAI trace]

Here are my findings here:

- The server is returning 204
- Being the database involved, it is 100% writing data to database (401s do not involve database access from EF)
- Exception analysis finds the JWK specified in the exception

### Exception analysis

Looking at the thrown exception, here is the descriptive text from AAI

```
IDX10516: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: 
kid: 'RMHQYNQ4TV9KUHI2EI-INM-XYSOF_1RETVYMWQGE'.
Exceptions caught:
 ''. 
token: '{"alg":"RS256","kid":"RMHQYNQ4TV9KUHI2EI-INM-XYSOF_1RETVYMWQGE","typ":"at+jwt"}.{"sub":"SendgridWebhook","name":"Sendgrid Webhook API","oi_prst":"SendgridWebhook","client_id":"SendgridWebhook","oi_tkn_id":"8d0d5f94-2094-4a21-b84d-304d1d99e3fb","exp":1629910230,"iss":"https://****.azurewebsites.net/","iat":1629906630}'. Valid Lifetime: 'True'. Valid Issuer: 'False'
```

Stack trace

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenUnableToValidateException:
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.InternalValidators.ValidateLifetimeAndIssuerAfterSignatureNotValidatedJwt (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=6.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature (System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken (System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler+<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
```

I determined that the following happens

1. The application receives a JWT
2. Since there are multiple OIDC providers registered, the runtime fetches the JWKs both of B2C and the self application
3. The JWT is validated against B2C keys, fails
4. The JWT is validated against the self keys, success
5. Access is granted

I believe that somewhere in the framework the code is well structured like the following. Since there are multiple providers to try, only if all of them fail the exception is thrown. Otherwise the simple for cycle acts as recovery to the exception

```
object principal = null;
Exception toThrow = null;
for (IAuthenticationProvider provider: GetProviders) {
    try {
        principal = provider.Authenticate(jwt);
    } catch(SomeKindOfJwtException ex) {
        toThrow = ex;
    }
}
if (principal == null) //and perhaps the exception is not null
    throw toThrow;
```

Look at that JWK `RMHQYNQ4TV9KUHI2EI-INM-XYSOF_1RETVYMWQGE`, I could easily find it by navigating `https://***.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/jwks` from my browser

```
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kid": "RMHQYNQ4TV9KUHI2EI-INM-XYSOF_1RETVYMWQGE",
      "use": "sig",
      "kty": "RSA",
      "alg": "RS256",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "n": "rMhqYnq4tv9kuHi2Ei-Inm-xysof_1retVymwqGeQ4hnlCRgrMAODGD4qxybhnpufuitEQRckCb4P49O_qafSQ0ocgRRIIuQJc-vLhLJHGp681_9cZT-jGxHnGw5Jdr0NZxH8RwV6cXcmpRN6f2WupujyhLLNwuu8aaTrucHA3JXshib9ad9R96OacT1r6X77HHXdSzURLRWH-f2JFwpBjOvVfJPxW4dzPY0BT7CzP3lxVvGiNXOp4-E8kVz1jER2EP5wO0Ho2qjlIbGUvGF1ui7GxLItldDs-PkZOGGvsO7yS7aeQHSiMTJt7EO-w-ffCJYv-ZColAiHO9jNL0NmQ"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am also doing too much and peeking into Microsoft sources. [Here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/08e98d190301804748f646f681b93e82a6111ebb/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/InternalValidators.cs#L86) should be the point where the exception is thrown and *maybe* [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/cb32a870d71cc1da86dbb9dbcb824d10c15bd4db/src/Security/Authentication/JwtBearer/src/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L121) where the exception is logged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can I do in order to either fix or whitelist these exceptions?

Add a [telemetry filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling). Based on the exception telemetry you can decide to discard the telemetry.

> Question 2: when do exceptions get logged to AAI? Only when they are unhandled or when the logger decides to?

When unhandled, or when instructed to do so. For example, when an exception is logged using `ILogger` it will be logged to AAI as well when using the AAI ILogger ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core))

Comment: Judging from the code by Microsoft that I linked, the JWTHandler logs failed attempts to the logger, which is configured to log to AAI. I'll try filtering the telemetry and I expect to place a green checkmark on the answer

Comment: Don't suppose you can post a sample filter to achieve this?  I have the exact same scenario and I suspect a filter is the only way to reduce the noise in AAI.  Thanks!